# "The underlying provider failed to Open" exception on IIS Local Machine using WEB API and Entity Framework Project

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API 2 project which works perfectly with local IIS express, but when I deploy on my local machine IIS, I get the error below:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "The underlying provider failed on Open.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException",
  "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass49.<ExecuteFunction>b__47()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction(String functionName, ObjectParameter[] parameters)\r\n   at ServiceDBUtility.FamLinkEntities.MBSP_INSERT_ERROR_LOG(String p_ID_USER, String p_ERROR_MSG, String p_ERROR_TRACE, String p_ERROR_TYPE, String p_REQUEST_URL, Nullable`1 p_ERROR_DATE)\r\n   at ServiceDBUtility.Repository.LogRepository.WriteLog(String p_ID_USER, String p_ERROR_MSG, String p_ERROR_TRACE, String p_ERROR_TYPE, String p_REQUEST_URL, Nullable`1 p_ERROR_DATE)\r\n   at ServiceDBUtility.CommonFunctions.WriteLog(String USER_ID, Exception Ex, String reqURL)\r\n   at ServiceDBUtility.CommonFunctions.ThrowException(Exception e, HttpRequestMessage request, String customErrorMessage)\r\n   at LoginService.Controllers.LoginController.Login()\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
  "InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Login failed for user ''.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()"
  }
}
```

Can someone provide insight into what might be causing this error?

Comment: Proper capitalization, punctuation, and grammar can help readers more easily understand your problem, resulting in a higher chance of getting a timely and accurate answer.

Comment: If you are using integrated security to connect to database you need to run your application pool under that user credential. By default your application pool run under ApplicationPoolIdentity  Identity.

Comment: Thanks , This helped me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I solved this issue ,

1. Press  WIN + R
2. Type inetmgr and press enter
3. Select Application pool
4. Select Advanced Settings from Right side
5. Go to Identity and select Custom Account
6. Provide Username and password of the active directory.

Answer (score 0):

@mahesh - By looking at the stack trace, it appears some login/authentication issue exists (find the extract from log).  Please check the credentials/access on SQL Server.

d__1.MoveNext()",
  "InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Login failed for user ''.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",
    "StackTrace": "   at

Answer (score 0):

For future references, this is usually an SQL Server error, before touching your code, open SQL Server Management Studio, see if you're able to login, chances are you won't be. Then open SQL Server Configuration Manager and make sure your server is running.